# Merging specific columns of 2 files based on field match

Tags: text-processing, awk, join, bioinformatics

I know I'm not the first one asking this but my code still does not work:

**File 1:**

```
gi|1283| tRNAscan exon 87020 88058 . - . transcript_id "Parent=tRNA-Tyr5.r01";
gi|3283| tRNAscan exon 97020 97058 . + . transcript_id "Parent=tRNA-Tyr6.r01";
gi|4283| rRNAscan exon 197020 197058 . - . transcript_id "Parent=rRNA-Tyr1.r01";
gi|5283| mRNAscan exon 295020 298059 . + . transcript_id "Parent=mRNA-Tyr2.r01";
```

This file is tab separated.

**File 2:**

```
"Parent=tRNA-Tyr6.r01"; 12
"Parent=mRNA-Tyr2.r01"; 0
```

This file is also tab separated.

**Desired output:**

```
"Parent=tRNA-Tyr6.r01"; 12 -
"Parent=mRNA-Tyr2.r01"; 0 +
```

I want to merge these two files based on column $10 in file 1 (`"Parent=tRNA-Tyr6.r01";`) and column $1 in file 2 (`"Parent=tRNA-Tyr6.r01";`), appending column $7 from file 1 (`-`/`+`)

My solution would go like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$10]=$7;next} ($1 in a) {print $1,"2,a[$1]}' file2 file1 > Output
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should reverse the order of input files.

Answer (score 1):

The [`join`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation) utility merges lines of two files based on a common column. It requires the files to be sorted on that column.

```
join -t $'\t' -1 10 -2 1 -o 2.1,2.2,1.7 <(sort -t $'\t' -k10 file1) <(sort -t $'\t' file2)
```

- `$'\t'` is a tab character, `-t $'\t'` says to use that as the field separator.
- `join -1 10 -2 1` means to join lines when the field 10 of the first file matches field 1 of the second file.
- `-o …` lists the fields to output.
- `<(sort …)` uses the output of the `sort` command as one of the inputs of `join`.

`$'…'` and `<(…)` require ksh or bash, they don't work in plain sh.

If `file2` is already sorted then you can use this, which works in plain sh:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k10 file1 |
join -t "$(printf \\t)" -1 10 -2 1 -o 2.1,2.2,1.7 - file2
```

If you want to preserve the order of one of the files, you can still use `join`, but first add line numbers, and at the end sort by the original line numbers. For example, to preserve the order of `file2`:

```
join -t $'\t' -1 10 -2 1 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,1.7 \
     <(sort -t $'\t' -k10 file1) \
     <(<file2 nl | sort -t $'\t' -k 2,2) |
sort | cut -d $'\t' -f 2-
```